# Kubernetes: node: NotReady, pod stays ready. Why?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kuberntes cluster consisting of 1 master and 3 worker nodes on bare metal.

I am running elasticsearch as statefulset with readinessProbe and livenessProbe. For forwaring kibana traffic, kibana is pointing to headless-service of Elasticsearch.
When an elasticsearch node is starting, the pod is first shown as 0/1 ready, when Elasticsearch node is ready, it is showing READY 1/1 as expected.

But it is not working if I want to break a node by stopping docker daemon on a worker node which runs elasticsearch. The node is shown as NotReady, the elasticsearch pod is still shown as ready. So the Service is still routing to the unavailable pod which produces timeouts on client side.

When I describe the pod, I can see that **no new readiness probes** are failing. Seems as if they are not fired against pods on an NotReady node.

I expect all pods to be unavailable / not ready, if a node becomes NotReady.

How do I do this?

Thanks, Andreas